# Azure VM not receiving SMTP from Internet

Tags: asp.net, email, azure, iis, smtp

My New Azure Windows Server 2012 R2 is not receiving emails to C:\inetpub\Mailroot\Drop\ from Internet that need to be read from mail drop folder by my ASP.NET app.

My Email Domain provider is Yahoo.
I changed Yahoo email MX and A Record to my VM Public virtual IP (VIP) address.
I send an email to my domain.
The email does not show up in incoming SNMP folder:  C:\inetpub\mailroot\Drop\

This has worked on my previous Windows Server 2008 R2 box at my home.  Now I'm trying to migrate to Azure.

Comment: Just FYI: The IIS inbound mailserver functionality is [deprecated since WS2012](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831568.aspx). I suggest using some alternative like [hMailServer](https://www.hmailserver.com/) or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add endpoint:
DASHBOARD >  > ENDPOINTS menu > ADD > NAME: SMTP

Start SMTP:
Start button > Admin Tools > IIS6 > right-click SMTP Virtual Server > START

Receive email in:
"C:\inetpub\Mailroot\Queue"

Comment: But why doesn't it go into \Pickup like it used to on my Windows 2008 server?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your firewalls both on the virtual machine an on azure to allow port 25.

Comment: VM's Windows control panel > Windows Firewall has been open.  Where is this azure firewall?

Comment: here is an article that shows how to configure it [Azure Endpoints](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/)

Comment: ok.  I did DASHBOARD > <VM> > ENDPOINTS menu > ADD > NAME: SMTP.  I restated.  To test, I did PowerShell > TELNET LOCALHOST 25 but I get "Connect failed"

Comment: No:  that's where I just did the TELNET LOCALHOST 25 test.  That's the only way I know to test on the local Azure VM SMTP machine.

Comment: Ah ok if it won't work locally it won't work remotely. I would verify that the smtp service is running and configured properly. [follow this to set it up](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/78873-so-you-need-to-setup-a-smtp-relay-in-windows-2012-r2-iis-6) specifically check your authentication.

Comment: TELENET LOCALHOST 25 now works.  Had to do:  Start > Admin Tools > IIS6 > right-click SMTP Virtual Server > START.  I already set Yahoo MX and A records for my email domain.  But Internet email still not getting to Azure's C:\inetpub\mailroot\Drop\    I will try WireShark to see if it's getting to Azure.

Comment: Now try to telnet remotely use the vm external IP address in your telnet instead of local host from a machine not in azure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96264/discussion-between-doug-null-and-josh-pendergrass).

Comment: Josh, does Windows 2012 server still have the capability to send out SMTP by writing the email file to \inetpu\mailroot\pickup\ ?  It's not working for me.